# Adapting Dijkstra to list all shortest paths

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, enumeration

I found a code in the internet for Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm in PHP. The problem is it only shows one possible path. If there are several paths having the same distance, it only outputs one of them.

> How can I modify this algorithm to produce all shortest paths?

`//set the distance array
$_distArr = array();
$_distArr[1][2] = 7;
$_distArr[1][3] = 9;
$_distArr[1][6] = 14;
$_distArr[2][1] = 7;
$_distArr[2][3] = 10;
$_distArr[2][4] = 15;
$_distArr[3][1] = 9;
$_distArr[3][2] = 10;
$_distArr[3][4] = 11;
$_distArr[3][6] = 2;
$_distArr[4][2] = 15;
$_distArr[4][3] = 11;
$_distArr[4][5] = 6;
$_distArr[5][4] = 6;
$_distArr[5][6] = 9;
$_distArr[6][1] = 14;
$_distArr[6][3] = 2;
$_distArr[6][5] = 9;

//the start and the end
$a = 1;
$b = 6;

//initialize the array for storing
$S = array();//the nearest path with its parent and weight
$Q = array();//the left nodes without the nearest path
foreach(array_keys($_distArr) as $val) $Q[$val] = 99999;
$Q[$a] = 0;

//start calculating
while(!empty($Q)){
    $min = array_search(min($Q), $Q);//the most min weight
    if($min == $b) break;
    foreach($_distArr[$min] as $key=>$val) if(!empty($Q[$key]) && $Q[$min] + $val < $Q[$key]) {
        $Q[$key] = $Q[$min] + $val;
        $S[$key] = array($min, $Q[$key]);
    }
    unset($Q[$min]);
}

//list the path
$path = array();
$pos = $b;
while($pos != $a){
    $path[] = $pos;
    $pos = $S[$pos][0];
}
$path[] = $a;
$path = array_reverse($path);

//print result

echo "
From $a  to  $b";
echo "
The length is ".$S[$b][1];
echo "
Path is ".implode('->', $path);

?>`

Comment: There's no search algorithm in the code you showed, only what seems to be the steps to print the path once it's been calculated.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: **Heads up:** There can be an exponential number of shortest paths between two vertices.

Comment: For example, if all the distances are zero, so each path is a shortest path.  That even gives you an infinite number of shortest paths.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: @gnasher729 We usually want to talk about *simple* paths only. But that, still, leaves us with super-exponentially many paths at worst, which is not all that different from infinity in practice. ;)